# Keep variable up to date when appending to the dom

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What's a good technique for keeping a reference to a list of items up to date?

Ideally when I append an element to the DOM i'd like my variable holding a list of that type of element to be updated.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
var ListOfItems = $("ul");
var Items = $("li");

alert(Items.length);

var NewItem = $("<li></li>");
ListOfItems.append(NewItem);
alert(Items.length);
```

**Output:**

```
5
5
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S84yY/

Comment: it is rather unclear what you wish but maybe implementing the mutation observers events are what you're looking for.

Comment: rerun the selectors or do `Items.push(NewItem);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its no way for binding, the better way you have is after this line:

```
ListOfItems.append(NewItem);
```

add it to your array with this:

```
Items.push(NewItem);
```

or update your array again with this:

```
Items = $("li");
```

Comment: Ah nice, I think pushing the item to the array would be more suitable for my use case :) I've tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/S84yY/1/